# What is the dresscode for jurors in Australian courts?

Tags: australia, rules-of-court, jury

Are there any rules and regulations jurors in Australian courts have to abide by when it comes to how they are dressed in court? If so, what would be the consequences of violating them? Can jurors be reported for contempt of court if their outfit is considered improper?

Comment: no opinion questions. You could frame this better asking for where the line is for contempt-of-court with clothing. Generally, the courts advise to not show midriff or thighs.

Comment: I rewrote the question to be more objective and less trollish. Also removed the example picture because that makes this "specific legal advise".

Comment: very relevent/possible source of idea: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/90571/jury-misconduct/90587#90587

Comment: Dress code for jurors: Dressed. (Just joking). I guess if you wear clothes that would get you arrested outside the court, then you'll get arrested inside the court as well.

Comment: @gnasher729 I don't know about Australia, but in most of Europe you can basically wear (or not wear) whatever you want. There's not even a law that forbids shopping naked. There might be some questions asked, but it's not _illegal_ in itself.

Comment: @Philipp regarding the original image, would that be appropriate for court?

Answer (score 1):

[new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales)

> Make sure you are dressed neatly. You do not need to wear a suit but you should not wear singlets, thongs, untidy, revealing or ripped clothing. ​​

[What to do, say and wear in court](https://www.lawaccess.nsw.gov.au/Pages/representing/getting_ready_for_court/lawassist_what_to_do_say_and_wear_in_court.aspx)

Failure to adhere to the dress code is unlikely to be, of itself, [contempt of court](https://www.judcom.nsw.gov.au/publications/benchbks/local/contempt_in_the_face_of_the_court.html). Depending on the circumstances and the temperament of the presiding officer, it might be ignored or the person might be ordered to leave the court, possibly with an order to return suitably dressed. Failure to follow an order of the court *is* contempt. So, for example, if a person called for jury service was inappropriately dressed, the judge might order them to attend the next day correctly attired: if they didn’t, then they might hold them in contempt for failing to follow the order, not for being inappropriately dressed.

Comment: Is the original image I posted suitable?